# pivot_longer for multiple observations in a row

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have a data set with a multiple observations within 1 row that I am trying to reshape into a long format. Here's what the data will look like

```
    df_have <- data.frame(group = c(1,2), p1_age = c(18,30), p1_sex = c("male", "male"),
                   p2_age = c(22,51), p2_sex = c("female", "male"))

  group p1_age p1_sex p2_age p2_sex
1     1     18   male     22 female
2     2     30   male     51   male
```

There will be more persons and variables that I want to reshape. I want to reshape it so it looks something like this:

```
    df_want <- data.frame(person = c(1,2,1,2), group = c(1,1,2,2), age = c(18,22,30,51),
                   sex = c("male", "female", "male", "male"))
  person group age    sex
1      1     1  18   male
2      2     1  22 female
3      1     2  30   male
4      2     2  51   male
```

I've tried using ".value" in a pivot_longer step to try and generate the what I want, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_longer` and specify the `names_pattern` to capture the digits (`\\d+`) and the word (`\\w+`) after the `_`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_have %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = c("person", ".value"),
       names_pattern = ".(\\d+)_(\\w+)")%>% 
     mutate(person = as.integer(person))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  group person   age sex   
  <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 1         18 male  
2     1 2         22 female
3     2 1         30 male  
4     2 2         51 male
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
pivot_longer(df_have, -group, names_to = c("person", ".value"), names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  group person    age sex   
  <dbl>  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1  p1       18 male  
2     1  p2       22 female
3     2  p1       30 male  
4     2  p2       51 male
```

Comment: A way to make 'person' an integer variable with just numeric data would be preferable. This is helpful though!

Comment: @milan_filip in that case you will need the `names_pattern = '(\\d+)_(.*)'` instead of the `names_sep = '_'` argument. Or once you run the above code, you could then use ` ...%>% mutate(parse_integer(person))`  in order to get the integer part of the `person`